# Parse Local Datastore: can't fetch pinned objects

Tags: ios, parse-platform, local-datastore

My app is storing `contact` objects in local datastore. It simply copy all the Address Book contacts into the Parse Local Datastore. In my case I create about 200 new contacts and I store them with this line of code:

```
PFObject.pinAllInBackground(addressBookContacts, block: { (contact) -> () in NSLog("contacts pinned")})
```

**Each time my app is launched, I look for stored object to present them to user with this query:**

```
let localQuery = PFQuery(className: "Contact")
localQuery.fromLocalDatastore()
localQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (localresults: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    // show contacts to the user
})
```

**If there are no contacts found, I go through the Address Book and create them again.**

The problem is that the query does not return anything in some cases.
I launch the app, wait till "contacts pinned" appeared in the console(just to be sure the pin callback is called) and rerun the app again and again - eventually the query return duplicated contacts (about 800 of them), so I'm sure the pinning was successful in previous attempts but the query does not see them in most cases. Why does it happen?

**UPDATE**

I've wrapped my fetch method in a `dispatch_after` block, to delay the query for a few seconds and that have fixed the bug! Looks like my query is trying to fetch the local datastore while it is not ready yet? No error messages in query callbacks, no nothing.

Comment: Are you making sure to query the local database AFTER the objects have been pinned in the callback. From your code it seems your trying to query before anything is actually saved to the local datastore.

Comment: @DBoyer 1st launch: 200 contacts fetched and pinned. 2nd launch: trying to fetch them with a query - nothing found, creating another 200 contacts. 3rd launch - same as 2nd. 3rd launch - same as 3rd and 2nd. 5th launch - 800 contacts found with the same query as before.

Comment: @DBoyer see the `update` section

Comment: LDS pinning right now takes an abnormal amount of time when pinning objects that contain other containers (dictionaries, arrays, extended ACLS, etc.). While this will be fixed in the future, right now our recommended approach is to persist as flat of objects as possible to LDS. (Source: Dev on Parse).

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII there is no problem with pinning duration

Comment: Did you make sure the enable the local datastore feature before setting your applicationID. This is a required step for your query to work.

Comment: @DBoyer yes, `Parse.enableLocalDatastore()` is indeed called before `Parse.setApplicationId..`

Comment: Are you making sure that you called saveInBackground or saveEventually on all the contacts after creating them?

Comment: @DBoyer I never save contacts to cloud, I use only local datastore and pinning.

Comment: I would investigate this then being the problem, I assumed you did have to save them to the cloud otherwise you might as well just use Core Data. I'd be very surprised if you didn't have to save them first, I am pretty sure I read somewhere that you at least need to call saveEventually

Comment: @DBoyer no doubt, LDS is very bad idea to store local information because of slow performance, I've already felt it, but anyway the durability  problem which I faced here must be fixed.

Comment: Were you able to find out what the problem is? My LocalDatastore query returns empty regardless of what I do

Comment: @AceGreen no, still don't have any idea of what may cause the problem. It looks like race condition problems while datastore initialization. Parse became open source about a week ago, so anyone can investigate whats going on under the hood.